# Evaluate SQL expressions in Java?

Tags: java, sql

In our project, we need to evaluate SQL statements without any database server. Can you suggest any free Java library that has the ability to evaluate math based SQL statements and return the result?

For example;

### Input

`SELECT 2*2 AS RESULT`

### Output

`4`

Will probably be called as `int result = SQLEvaluator.evaluate("SELECT 2*2 AS RESULT");`

Comment: Did you try googling this?  Voting to close as NC.  It's a shopping list question.

Comment: I actually googled it a lot. But what I could find is just sql parsers. I need a simple sql expression evaluation engine for mathematical queries as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to achieve that using [ZQL](http://zql.sourceforge.net/) as seen in the code below. But I seriously advise you pick a simple embedded database such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) ([example here](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/test/org/h2/samples/HelloWorld.java?r=3290)) and use it instead (the project health is much higher).

### Using H2:

```
public class H2ExpEval {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        evaluateUsingH2("SELECT 2+2");
        evaluateUsingH2("SELECT 3+7-5");
        evaluateUsingH2("SELECT 2*2*2+1");
    }

    private static void evaluateUsingH2(String sql) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        // opens an in-memory database: no files are saved and it's all quicker
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        stat.close(); conn.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
5
9
```

To use it, add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.171</version>
</dependency>
```

## Using ZQL:

```
public class ZqlEvalDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(evaluate("SELECT 2+2 FROM RESULT;"));
        System.out.println(evaluate("SELECT 3+7-5 FROM RESULT;"));
        System.out.println(evaluate("SELECT 2*2*2+1 FROM RESULT;"));
    }

    private static ZqlParser p = new ZqlParser();
    private static Object evaluate(String s) throws Exception {
        p.initParser(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()));
        ZStatement st = p.readStatement();
        ZSelectItem zSelectItem = ((ZQuery) st).getSelect().get(0);
        ZExpression exp = (ZExpression) zSelectItem.getExpression();
        return new ZEval().evalExpValue(new ZTuple(), exp);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4.0
5.0
9.0
```

For the dependencies, either download from the [ZQL Page](http://zql.sourceforge.net/) or, for testing purposes, add this to your `pom.xml` (testing purposes because we don't know who maintains that repository):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.experlog</groupId>
    <artifactId>zql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>zql</id>
    <name>zql</name>
    <url>http://dbappserv.cis.upenn.edu:8080/artifactory/ext-releases-local</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: We tried ZQL but it doesn' t accept some specific SQL words like `'CASE WHEN...'` etc. After that we tried H2 and Derby in memory database options and decided to use H2. Thanks a lot really :)

Comment: @Alpay I believe you made the right choice. To parse more complicated cases, you'd have to learn more and more of ZQL's complexities. Using the database is just plain ol' SQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use an embedded java-only database server, like java Derby, HSQL or others with a non-persistent in-memory database. The advantage being the existence of a *real* standards compliant engine.

On that a thin wrapper might be provided with the Java Scripting API, so you can work with variables and functions too.

---

***Usage of scripting would be***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : manager.getEngineFactories()) {
        System.out.printf("language: %s, engine: %s%n", factory.getLanguageName(), factory.getEngineName());
    }
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("SQL");
    try {
        Object result = engine.eval("SELECT 1+2;");
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

***Implementing SQL for the Java Scripting API***

Make a project for sqlscript.jar with a text file:

```
/META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory
```

containing:

```
my.sqlscript.SQLScriptEngineFactory
```

The engine factory class can so be discovered, by language name for instance.
It delivers a ScriptEngine for evaluation.

```
package my.sqlscript;
public class SQLScriptEngineFactory implements ScriptEngineFactory {
    @Override
    public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine() {
        return new SQLScriptEngine(this);
    }
}
```

The engine can do the work. Here I used HSQLDB, which has a problem with a SELECT without FROM, but the same can be done even better with JavaDB / Derby pr H2SQL.
Not that the available parameter binding would need a bit plumbing too.

```
public class SQLScriptEngine extends AbstractScriptEngine {

private final SQLScriptEngineFactory factory;

public SQLScriptEngine(SQLScriptEngineFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}

@Override
public Object eval(String script, ScriptContext context)
        throws ScriptException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Multi-column/multi-row result
    Object singleValue = null; // Single value result

    Server hsqlServer = new Server();
    try {
        File dbFile = File.createTempFile("sqlscript", ".db");
        String dbURL = dbFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
        hsqlServer.setLogWriter(null);
        hsqlServer.setSilent(true);
        hsqlServer.setDatabaseName(0, "db1");
        hsqlServer.setDatabasePath(0, dbURL);
    } catch (IOException | MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new ScriptException(ex);
    }
    hsqlServer.start();

    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db1", "sa", "");
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(script);
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();) {

            ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = meta.getColumnCount();                
            int row = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int column = 1; column <= columns; ++column) {
                    Object value = rs.getObject(column);
                    singleValue = row == 1 && column == 1? value : null;
                    sb.append(value);
                    if (column < columns) {
                        sb.append("\t");
                    }
                }
                sb.append("\n");
                ++row;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e2) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLScriptEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e2);
    }

    hsqlServer.stop();
    return singleValue != null ? singleValue : sb.toString();
}
}
```

You could make the connection more persistent in the factory class, and have a pseudo SQL statement `shutdown` to close the connection explicitly.

***Conclusion***

It is a relatively easy layer of abstraction, which could help in reuse. Other than providing your own classes.

Comment: can you provide any example showing how Java Scripting API evaluates SQL scripts?

Comment: Above is a bit of example code. You could look into the sources of the Groovy Scripting Engine. Especially of interest as a search on the scripting API will find more usages than own providers.